# Magento auto login from external site, same domain

Tags: php, magento

I have problem with logging into magento from my external site. 
I have done researches about it, and tried several codes on web but after logged in from my external site, it won't automatically logged into the magento website.

this is my log in form.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

function validatePassword($password, $hash) {
$hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
switch(count($hashArr)) {
    case 1:
        return md5($password) === $hash;
    case 2:
        return md5($hashArr[1].$password) === $hashArr[0];
}
return false;
}

$apiUrl = 'http://magentowebsite.com/api/soap/?wsdl';
$apiUser = 'USER API';
$apiKey = 'PASSWORD';

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
try {
    $client = new SoapClient($apiUrl);
    $session = $client->login($apiUser, $apiKey);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}


//Lookup customer record
list($customer) = $client->call(
    $session,
    'customer.list',
    array(
        array(
            'email' => addslashes($_POST['login']['username'])
        )
    )
);
if(is_array($customer)) {
    if(validatePassword($_POST['login']['password'], $customer['password_hash'])) {

        require_once 'app/Mage.php';
        umask(0);
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('default');

        Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
        $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

        //Log out any existing sessions
        if(!$session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $session->logout();
        }

        //Log user in
        $login = Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);

        header('Location: http://www.magentowebsite.com/');
        exit;

        exit;
    } else {
        header('Location: http://www.myexternalloginsite.com?ref=invalid');
        exit;
    }
} 
else {
        header('Location: http://www.myexternalloginsite.com?ref=invalid');
        exit;
}
}

}

?>


<form action="http://www.myexternalloginsite.com" method="post">
<div class="login_field">
    <label for="login_username">Username</label>
    <input id="login_username" type="text" value="" name="login[username]" />
</div>
<div class="login_field">
    <label for="login_password">Password</label>
    <input id="login_password" type="password" value=""  name="login[password]" />
</div>
<div class="login_field">
    <input type="submit" value="log in" />
</div>
</form>
```

The form works well, I mean it can load and then redirect me to the magento site. but not logged in as the user using previous credentials. What am i missing here? is there any configuration I need to change in the magento admin panel?

thank you